# cfhttp peer not authenticated error in coldfusion 9 enterprise

Tags: coldfusion

I am working on a old server which is running CF9 and is still a part of the development of the company. I have to make a `<cfhttp>` call to get a response from a website. If I run it in a browser, I get the expected response in XML. However, when I make a `<cfhttp>` call, it just throws an error.

**Code:**

```
<cfset objSecurity = createObject("java", "java.security.Security") /> 
<cfset storeProvider = objSecurity.getProvider("JsafeJCE") /> 
<cfset objSecurity.removeProvider("JsafeJCE") />

<cfhttp url="https://apiwebsite/api/integration/v1/events/a200363c-6b8f-4876-8cd0-105d41bb2fdf?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=73aa7a7d2bfdff27fd04e3967e313d5d&oauth_timestamp=1495298341&oauth_consumer_key=consumer_key&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=btkwYPlWGuquUOpwUNPFcLA17q8%3D"/>

<cfset objSecurity.insertProviderAt(storeProvider, 1) />

<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

**Error from cfdump:**

```
ErrorDetail I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Filecontent Connection Failure
Header      [empty string]
Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file.
```

It is so frustrating as I do not know how to fix it. I am open to looking around at custom tags if needed.

Comment: I believe this has been asked before. CF9 has issues with newer SSL certain & SNI wildcard domains. If using IIS, you can use CFC_HTTP5. Another option is to use CFExecute and CURL.

Comment: CFC_HTTP5 or CFX_HTTP5. I tried ading the custom tag and the bloody java applet does not load, it shows it is being blocked with some settings which i can't figure out

Comment: It's not java. It's C++. Which web server and ColdFusion version are you using? It works on all Windows/IIS/ColdFusion servers I've ever tried it on so far.

Comment: I knowis c++ based, but the applet when we browse the server to find it in a java tree that is blocked by the security settings of the browser and i with media template, raised a ticket with them, hopefully i may be able to get it fixed

Comment: Enter the file path manually (if you know it). We've never used the java file browser as it never seemed to work in our browsers either.

Comment: oh, you mean to say, just use c:/stuff, let me try that

Comment: Can you givemme an example of curl and cfexecute @james Mobers

Comment: To perform an *HTTPS GET* request?  Full documentation is available online at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html   Basic use = `CURL https://website.com/api/ -d "key=123&method=getStuff"`